# Koin: Passing Properties between different module definitions

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

Was testing the following code. For brevity:

```
 Class ActivityA {
        Val aViewModel: AViewModel by viewModel()

         Fun onCreate(){
            val id = ….
            getKoin().setProperty(“id’”, id)
             loadKoinModules(aModule)
         }
    }
```

And in my modules.kt definitions:

```
Val aModule = modules {
    viewModel { AViewModel(getProperty(“id”))}  //works
    }

     //For ActivityB
        Val bModule = modules {
            viewModel { BViewModel(getProperty(“id”)} // Caused by: org.koin.core.error.MissingPropertyException: Property 'Id' not found
        }
```

Why do I get this error when trying to create the BViewModel instance. I would have thought that getKoin() would be the same Koin Instance retrieved. But it seems to work only within the same Module definition loaded. I can’t get the property ‘id’ for module B. I have to do the same in ActivityA’s onCreate() for ActivityB.

Any explanation or links regarding this would be appreciated or do I have to use something like Koins' Scope feature for this?

Many Thanks